# How to redirect to a different controller action in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-acl

I am creating a simple website where users can sign up, and then sign in and add text articles. Without signing in, a visitor will have the role of a guest, and will only be able to view articles. I am doing this as an exercise in Zend framework 1, as I have just begun learning Zend. I will make a controller AuthController for login, but I want to know how do I redirect to the login action in that controller, from my indexAction in IndexController. Also, how do I make use of a custom plugin to implement this kind of access control? How do I invoke it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can redirect inside an action method using:

```
$this->redirect('/module/controller/action/');
```

Comment: I guess this was renamed to $this->redirect() in recent versions of ZF.

Answer (score 17):

jalpesh and Hasina are both correct with their short answers.

Jalpesh's example would be a shorthand call to the action helper `redirector()`, which defaults to the `gotoSimple()` method of redirection, except he seems to have the parameters backwards.

```
//corrected
$this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller);
```

would be more verbosely called as:

```
$this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = array());
```

There are several ways to use the [Redirector action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector), this is just a very common example.

The example provided by Hasina is a call to the controller [utility method `_redirect()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods) a much more limited bit of code then the `Redirector` helper is but still very useful.

```
//only accepts a url string as the first arg
//deprecated as of ZF 1.7 still in documentation
$this->_redirect($url, array $options = array());
```

apparently as of ZF 1.7 there is a new method not in the documentation (*found this bit in the docblock*) that is prefered:

```
//valid as of ZF 1.7, not in documentation
$this->redirect($url, array $options = array());
```

Both of these utility methods are proxies for:

```
 Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector::gotoUrl()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks RockyFord! using $this->_redirect('/auth/login') I get this error :The requested URL /demo/auth/login was not found on this server. My project folder is demo, inside which I have the folders application, library and public. The index.php is inside public, and I point my browser to localhost/demo/public/.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using routes, you can use `$this->getHelper('Redirector')->setGotoRoute(array(), 'routeName');`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you

```
$this->_helper->redirector('controller','action');
```

by this way you can call another controller.